# Setting Config path for Unit Tests for NxBRE

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, configuration, nxbre

I'm trying to run some unit-tests for NxBRE before I start referencing it's implementation in the rules-engine project I'm working on. I'm using versions NUnit 2.6 for testing NxBRE 3.2. Since NxBRE came with it's own unit tests in it's own friendly project folder that utilizes the NUnit.Framework, I figured it'd be a quick one-two outta there ka-poo. After making sure everything compiled, I went ahead and ran the tests...and got a million errors. Mostly along the lines of:

> NxBRE.Test.FlowEngine.TestBackwardChainer.CircularityDetection:
>   SetUp : System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file 'C:\car-loan-rules.xbre'.

or:

> NxBRE.Test.InferenceEngine.TestEngineCoreFeaturesRuleML091.TestEngineCoreFeaturesRuleML09.NxBREOperators:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not find file 'C:\test-0_91.ruleml'.

Befuddled, I went to the NxBRE website and looked for information about their unit-tests. This was all I could find: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/nxbre/wiki/UnitTesting

Which doesn't describe the process very specifically. How do I configure the engine so that the paths point to the correct location of the test rule bases? Is this something that I have to do in NUnit? Or in my IDE (SharpDevelop)? Also, I know where the output folder is, but how do I reckon which Dtd or Xml files that I need to copy there? This probably exposes my inexperience, which is where you guys' expertise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out--basically the unit-tests were pre-disposed to look in locations that didn't exist, and in fact bundled with the NxBRE was the pdf that defined the fields that needed to be defined for it to run.